# LocationManager and LOCATION_SERVICE

Tags: android

are these 2 lines equivalent?
They behave differently in my application.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Thanks

Comment: yes, the first would be from anything other than an activity or a service while the other would be from one of those 2. what is the problem you are having?

Comment: @tyczj why not posted as an anwer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes they are the same, the first would be from anything other than an `Activity` or a `Service` while the other would be from one of those 2.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'm not having a particular problem, I'm a noobie and I'm trying to wrap my head around these java concepts and still having some difficulties getting it right.
Is this difference between the 2 lines due to polymorpysm? and if so (or not), can you explain or help my identify the root of this difference, or how to visualize it or understand it in a different way?
Thank you

Comment: the difference being that Activyt and Service both derive from `Context` so those methods are inherited. for classes that are not derrived from context like fragments, you need to supply the context in order to use them.